# C# send emai with port 465

Tags: c#

I'm using .NET 4.5 SmtpClient, as i found out, that everything on port 465 just returns time out, my question is, is there a way to send emails with port 465 on .NET 4.5

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = email.Configuracao.Host.Trim(),
    Port = email.Configuracao.Port,
    EnableSsl = email.Configuracao.EnableSSL,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = email.Configuracao.UseDefaultCredentials,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email.Configuracao.Login.Trim(), email.Configuracao.Senha.Trim())
};

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((s, c, x, p) => { return true; });
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
try
{
    smtp.Send(mailMessage);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    var d = e;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(alternatePort))
    {
        smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(alternatePort);
        smtp.Send(mailMessage);
        alternatePort = "";
    }
}

mailMessage.Dispose();
```

Comment: How about a port map? http://woshub.com/port-forwarding-in-windows/

Comment: This question is confusing. You say that "everything on port 465 just returns time out", but then ask if there is "a way to send emails with port 465". If it always times out, why do you want to use that port? Your email server is not responding. Not much we (volunteers on the world wide web) can do about that. If you're asking how to use a *different* port, you've apparently got a configuration for the port value; change that to a different value.